# How to output console.log in Xcode (using wkwebview)?

Tags: ios, xcode, wkwebview

As a problem.

How to output console.log() in Xcode's console, in the case of wkwebview ?

(Objective-C)

Comment: NSLog in OBjective-C, or debugPrint() in swift, is irrelevant the component that you are using

Comment: @ReinierMelian  Is there any way to get the output of console.log? I want to get the logs in the webpage.